# On keypress event, how do I change a ',' to a '~'

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion-9

I have to prevent Coldfusion's default list delimiter ',' from being entered into a form input array. I am new to using javascript for validation purposes, and have never tried to switch out the values someone is typing in.  How can I snag a comma, and replace it with a tilda?

Javascript i've tried so far:

```
    $(document).ready(function(event){
      var regExComma = /,/;
      $("[name='name[]']").live("keypress",function(event){
// i know i could check the numerical value, i feel this requirement can get more added to it and I would like to just change the regEx accordingly.
        if(regExComma.test(String.fromCharCode(event.which)){
//it was a ',' switch it to '~'
         event.which = 126;
        }
      });
// added to show that the 'name' input form array is the only input that cares about the ','
    var regExDig = /[\d]/
    $("[name=min[]],[name=max[]]").live(keypress, function(event){
       if(!regExDig .test(String.fromCharCode(event.which)){
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#cfocFormMessages").trigger("updateMessages", {"url":"components.cfc/CFOC.cfc", "data":{"more":"stuff"}});
       }
    });
            });
```

cfml / html involved:

```
<form action="components/CatagoryService.cfc?method=saveVersion">
<input id="version" name="version" type="text">
<!--- .. more inputs ..--->
<table id="table">
  <thead><tr><th>name col</th>
  <th>min col</th>
  <th>max col</th>
  <th>edit</th>
</tr></thead>
  <tfoot></tfoot>
  <cfoutput query="variables.query">
  <tr><td><input name="name[]" type="text" value="#variables.query.name#"></td>
   <td><input name="min[]" type="text" value="#variables.query.min#"></td>
   <td><input name="max[]" type="text" value="#variables.query.max#"></td>
   <td><input name="id[]" type="hidden" value="#variables.query.id#">
     <a href="#" class="editLink">edit</a></td>
  </tr>
  </cfoutput>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td><a href="#" class="addLink">add</a></td></td></tr>
</table>
<input type="Submit"/>
</form>
```

if I alter CatagoryService.cfc?method=saveVersion to `<cfreturn arguments>` in a JSON string, a typical response from Coldfusion looks like:

```
{VERSION:"",name:"name1,name2",min:"1,3", max:"2,4",id:"1,2"}
```

Comment: What will happen if a user overrides your check and puts in a comma?  Will that be a security problem?  If so, you'll need to check on the server as well as on the client.

Comment: I am checking on the server too.  namely the 'name:"name1,name2" coldfusion list will be longer than the 'min' and 'max' lists.  I'll add code to show the other validation going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replaced the name[] .live()  `event.which = 126;` to `event.originalEvent.keyCode=126;`

```
var regExComma = /,/;
$("[name='name[]']").live("keypress",function(event){
     if(regExComma.test(String.fromCharCode(event.which)){
       //this line works as expected. and will swap out the value on keypress.
       if(event.originalEvent.keyCode){
         event.originalEvent.keyCode=126;
       }else if(event.originalEvent.charCode){
         event.originalEvent.charCode=126;
       }
     }
});
```

wolfram I upped your keyUp solution as well.

Comment: Keep in mind that this doesn't give you any security whatsoever. It doesn't even work if a user copies and pastes some invalid input. Always do validation on the server side. Also see my comment to the answer by Wolfram.

Comment: @Zed understood, this is Alongside server side validation, which has it's own set of error messages.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Chrome refuses to change the keyCode / charCode. After setting, it's still the same

Comment: The keyCode and charCode are readonly, see docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent

Answer (score 3):

I put [your HTML on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EutHr/2/) (you can test it there) and added this JavaScript, using a selector that matches all  and  elements:

```
$(document).ready(function(event){
    $(document).delegate("input, textarea", "keyup", function(event){
        if(event.which === 188) {
            var cleanedValue = $(this).val().replace(",","~");
            $(this).val(cleanedValue);
        }
    });
});
```

All commas in the value string are replaced by a tilde if a comma (code 188) was entered.

Remember that JavaScript validation is nothing you want to rely on. The commas can easily be send to the server or never get replaced, e.g. in a user agent with JavaScript disabled.

Comment: agreed, hence, why I don't like JS validation, and have to scrub before the server too.  This solution is running in an environment were JS is enabled all the time.

I'll switch to keyup and see how it goes!

Comment: The returned "which" codes are normalized by jQuery, but you might want to check that again cross-browser. Also, the "keypress" event returns the ASCII code (44), while keydown/keyup return the keyCode (188). Or you omit that check completely and always clean the string.

Comment: @DefyGravity: Remember that even if you can be sure that JavaScript is enabled all the time, any input validation that you do in JavaScript gives you absolutely nothing in terms of security. All it does is a convenient way for good users to know that they are writing something wrong before they submit the form. Any malicious user can inject JavaScript that turns off your validation or let the validation do its job and use Tamper Data plugin or something similar. This particular validation can even be defeated by simple copy and paste. Always use server-side validation even if JS is always on.

Answer (score 0):

Imho, there's no need to check those keyCodes:

```
 $(document).ready(function(event){
    $('#fieldName').keyup(function(event) {
        var cleanedValue = $(this).val().replace(",","~");
        $(this).val(cleanedValue);
    });
});
```

Check it on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DwnyF/).