# in coldfusion 9, How can I correctly submit form text input arrays containing "," in their text?

Tags: html, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I want to find a the best way to submit the html below to a cfc function.

```
<form action="test.cfc">
    <input type="hidden" name="method" value="save">
    <input type="text" name="mytext[]" value="f,oo">
    <input type="text" name="mytext[]" value="bar">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

test.cfc file contents:

```
    <cfcomponent displayname="test">
      <cffunction name="init">
      <cfreturn this>
    </cffunction>
    <cffunction name="save" output="false" returnformat="JSON" access="remote">
       <cfargument name="mytext" type="string" required="true">
       <!--- ***comments***  
         i want to do this:
         <cfloop list="arguments.mytext" index="curRowValue">
            <cfquery blah blah...>
   insert into fooBar (stuff) values (curRowValue)
</cfquery
         </cfloop>
       --->
       <cfreturn arguments>
    </cffunction>
    </cfcomponent>
```

the 'test.save()' function will return this json on my setup `{mytext:"f,oo,bar"}`  which would insert 3 rows instead of 2 if I uncommented the insert code.  What is the right way to intermingle user entered text and coldfusion's standard list delimiter?

Comment: this question was caused by this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266522/on-keypress-event-how-do-i-change-a-to-a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the handler, if you access the ColdFusion form scope itself, you've seen that CF will reduce same-named form field values to a single key-value pair, with values unhelpfully mashed together with commas.

But you can also access the raw request data and parse out the key-value pairs -- each of which will be distinct regardless of whether there are key name collisions. Here's a quick way to loop through the "actual" posted values:

```
arFormscope = gethttprequestdata().content.split('&');
for( i=1; i<=arraylen(arFormscope); i++ ){
  arElement = arFormscope[i].split('=');
  key = urldecode(arElement[1]);
  value = urldecode(arElement[2]);
  do_something_with( key, value ); // <-- your logic here
                                   // value == f,oo on first pass
                                   // value == bar on second pass
}
```

With your sample data, you'll get one pass through the loop for each `mytext[]` form field.

As a side note, you'll also get a trip through the loop for the submit button itself.

Comment: i replaced <cfreturn arguments> with <cfreturn getHttpRequestData()> and the "content" string was empty in the returned JSON.    calling a cfc function on form submit demands the cfc function to have 'access=remote' security.  I believe coldfusion is parsing the form and re-requesting against the function with the 'arguments' scope.

Comment: i think your idea would work if I changed the form action to a cfm page like marc esher mentioned in his comment in his answer

Comment: after changing the `<form action="fooBar.cfm">` i could loop through like your solution suggested.  not quite a `<form action="component.cfc"> solution, but is straightforward to use for what we need.

Answer (score 1):

Brian Kotek's FormUtilities is perfect for this. I can't imagine going back to NOT using this for all forms I build: http://www.briankotek.com/blog/index.cfm/2007/9/4/Implicit-Creation-of-Arrays-and-Structures-from-Form-Fields

Comment: +1 good idea, and is a decent work around.  however, I would need to pass in the 'arguments' struct in test.save() to a <cfset util.buildFormCollections(ARGUMENTS)>  would it still work?

Comment: You could change save() to take a structure, i.e. <cfargument name="formScope" type="struct">. Then, on your action page, which would be a .cfm page and not a .cfc, you'd do <cfset obj = new YourObjectWithASaveFunction()>  <cfset formData = util.buildFormCollections(form)>  <cfset obj.save(formData)>

Comment: marc, this solution works and i like it, but requires a large refactor on existing, old, dusty, scary code. going with Ken's answer for backwards compatibility