# Is it possible to change the keypress event in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I have gotten the code to work in IE. However, in Chrome the event does not get changed.
Is there a special way of doing this in Chrome, instead of assigning the `charCode`, `keyCode` and `which` variables to the value that I want?

I have posted my code at http://jsfiddle.net/qjpZN/5/

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have just tried your code in chrome and the console log shows the keypress.

Comment: i asked a similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5266522/176818) a while ago, and then the code had worked in chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `keydown` event instead. Chrome have a [known](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=2606) issue with `keypress` that maybe fixed in newer versions.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Looks as though I will have to change the codes for each character